# facing Datadog APM integration Issue with php application

Tags: datadog

We are getting below issue.

datadog.trace.agent.common.writer.ddagent.DDAgentApi - Error while sending 14 (size=6KB) traces. Total: 14, Received: 14, Sent: 0, Failed: 14. java.io.IOException: No such file or directory (Will not log errors for 5 minutes)

Can you please help us?

We are using terraform.

Dockerfile:

EXPOSE 8126
RUN DD_API_KEY=${DD_API_KEY} DD_SITE="datadoghq.eu" DD_HOSTNAME=${DD_HOSTNAME} DD_ENV=${DD_ENV} DD_APM_INSTRUMENTATION_ENABLED=host bash -c "$(curl -L https://s3.amazonaws.com/dd-agent/scripts/install_script_agent7.sh)"
RUN curl -LO https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-php/releases/latest/download/datadog-setup.php
RUN php datadog-setup.php --php-bin=all
RUN sed -i 
-e 's/;datadog.service = unnamed-php-service/datadog.service = tms/' 
/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/98-ddtrace.in

Datadog Agent.

Terraform Config:

{
"cpu": 1024,
"image": "public.ecr.aws/datadog/agent:latest",
"memory": 1024,
"name": "app-datadog-agent",
"networkMode": "awsvpc",
"essential": true,
"portMappings": [
{
"protocol": "tcp",
"containerPort": 8126
}
],
"environment": [
{
"name": "DD_API_KEY",
"value": "###"
},
{
"name": "ECS_FARGATE",
"value": "###"
},
{
"name": "DD_SITE",
"value": "###"
},
{
"name": "DD_APM_ENABLED",
"value": "true"
},
{
"name": "DD_APM_NON_LOCAL_TRAFFIC",
"value": "true"
}
]
}

We want to resolve the issue and enble apm tracing in datadog.